# How can I remove non word characters from a text?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want 'This Is A 101 Test' to be 'This Is A Test', but I can't get the syntax right.

```ruby
src = 'This Is A 101 Test'
puts "A) " + src                       # base => "This Is A 101 Test"
puts "B) " + src[/([a-z]+)/]           # only does first word => "his"
puts "C) " + src.gsub!(/\D/, "")       # Does digits, I want alphabetic => "101"
puts "D) " + src.gsub!(/\W///g)        # Nothing. => ""
puts "E) " + src.gsub(/(\W|\d)/, "")   # Nothing. => ""
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First off, you need to be careful with `gsub` and `gsub!`. The latter is "dangerous!" and will modify the value of `src`. If you're executing these statements in order, be aware that `a.gsub!(/a/, "b")` and `a = a.gsub(/a/, "b")` will both do the same thing to `a`. Part of the issue with your code is that `src` is being modified.

The B method returns `"his"` but makes no changes to `source`

```
src[/([a-z]+)/]     # => "his"
src                 # => "This Is A 101 Test"
```

The C method removes all characters that *aren't* numbers:

```
src.gsub!(/\D/, "") # => "101"
src                 # => "101"
```

The D method doesn't work because the syntax is wrong. The `gsub` method accepts a regular expression/string to search and then a string to use for replacement. If you try it in IRB it will act as though you need another `/` somewhere.

The E method replaces all non-word characters and all numbers:

```
src.gsub(/(\W|\d)/, "") # => "This Is A  Test" (note the two spaces)
src                     # => "This Is A 101 Test"
```

You point out that it's returning `""`. Well, what's actually happening is that C and D as listed (with syntax issues fixed) are *destructive* changes. (Also, if run on `"101"`, D will actually return `nil` as no substitutions were performed.) So E is just being run on `"101"`, and since you're replacing all non-words *and* all numbers with `""`, it becomes `"101"`.

---

The answer you're looking for would be something like:

```
src.gsub!(/\d\s?/, "") # => "This Is A Test"
src                    # => "This Is A Test"
```

And my favorite for dealing with all scenarios of double spaces (because `squeeze` is quite efficient at combining like characters, `strip` is quite efficient at stripping trailing whitespace, and those `!` return `nil` if they make no replacements):

```
src = src.gsub(/\d+/, "").squeeze(" ").strip
```

Answer (score 8):

To remove all "non word characters" you can instead keep only those.

```
src = 'This Is A 101 Test'
src.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z ]/,'').gsub(/ +/,' ')
=> "This Is A Test"
```

I recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for trying out Ruby regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

No regexp:

```
src = 'This Is A 101 Test'
src.delete('^a-zA-Z ') #the ^ negates everything
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to cut ' 101' from the string? Here's your regex

```
src = 'This Is A 101 Test'

puts src.gsub /\ \d+/, ''
# => This Is A Test
```

Also I don't understand why you are using bang version of `gsub`. `gsub!` modifies the original string, `gsub` copies it and modifies the copy.

Comment: Not working: `puts "F) " + src.gsub /\ d+/, ''
                       ^`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: it works. Your string is not what you think it is anymore. Change `gsub!` to `gsub` and try again.

Comment: Worked for me.  Do it exactly as he posted.  `puts src.gsub(/\ \d+/, '')`.  As @SergioTulentsev said, you shouldn't be using the `bang` version of the `gsub` method.  [Read the docs for the bang version](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21), it manipulates the original string.

Comment: I really get it now, the bangs operator in some of my lines was changing src.  Once I realized that and removed those lines (or at least the bang) the subsequent lines worked as expected.  I found this by outputting src at several points.  Thanks guys!

Comment: would like to accept both both had to pick 1 will upvote you however too.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want to delete numbers?  If so, `src.gsub(/\d/,"")` should work.  The reason it doesn't work above is that gsub! modifies the string it is called on, so after C, src = "101" and eliminating all digits leaves an empty string.

If you want to eliminate everything but alphabetic characters and spaces (ie digits and punctuation), `src.gsub(/(?=\S)(\d|\W)/,"")` should work.

If you want to eliminate everything but alphabetic characters (eliminating spaces as well as digits and punctuation), `src.gsub(/\d|\W/,"")` should work.